# "Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly" error after Intellij upgrade

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk

Upgraded to Intellij : Version: 13.1.3 Build: 135.909 and getting the error while trying to install Android application  :

```
  Waiting for device. 
Target device: samsung-gt_i9500-4d00a58cb4ea60a7 
Uploading file  local path: pathToAPK   
remote path: pathToApp  Installing App DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r"/data/local/tmp/App" pkg: /data/local/tmp/App Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]


    Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly. If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script.
```

Android SDK version is 1.7.0_25.
Installation worked correctly prior to Intellij upgrade

Comment: Are you using Gradle?

Comment: Is this a new project that shares the same package with an older one

Comment: nothing changed since Intellij upgrade in the project structure

Comment: So the fault is in the new version of Intellij